# Can I use this code below to take user input in an array? If not then how can I?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function arrinp() {
    var ar1 = [];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            prompt(ar1.push(ar1[i][j]));
        }
    }
}

arrinp();
```

Comment: If the form says add more text explaining your question, then it doesn't mean that you should format code as text..

Answer (score 0):

Sure, replace

```
    prompt(ar1.push(ar1[i][j]));
```

with

```
    ar1[i][j] = prompt("Enter value");
```

Complete code

```
function arrinp() {
  var ar1 = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ar1[i] = []; //observe this line as well
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      ar1[i][j] = prompt("Enter value"); 
    }
  }
  return ar1; //return the array
}

console.log(arrinp());
```

**Demo**

```js
function arrinp() {
  var ar1 = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ar1[i] = []; //observe this line as well
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      ar1[i][j] = prompt("Enter value"); 
    }
  }
  return ar1; //return the array
}

console.log(arrinp());
```